# how to find hidden field value from data list itemtemplete using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 with c#.

In my aspx page i want to get hidden field value which is in data list's itemtemplete.like

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlKit" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" width="100%">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 115px">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="DeviceId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Id")%>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="DeviceType" runat="server" Value='<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("DeviceType")) %>' />
                <asp:Label ID="lblDevicetype" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("DeviceType_Name")%>'></asp:Label> <span style="float: right;">:</span>

            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 0;">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfSelectedDeviceType" runat="server" Value="" />
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkDevice" runat="server" Checked="true" onclick="javascript:SelectRBTN(this);" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

In `SelectRBTN(this)` function i want to get `DeviceType`(hidden field) value.

How I get? please give proper solution for the same.

Comment: which code you tried for it ?

Comment: alert($(this).parents($("#<%=dlKit.ClientID%>")).find('DeviceType input[type="hidden"]').val());

Comment: means you want all hidden object value right?

Comment: yes. i want to value of that hidden field object.

Comment: @user2496448: Please see my updated answer. I have verified it to be correct. If still any issue, please convey. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It will select `DeviceType` in the respective row where the `chkDevice` is clicked.

```
function SelectRBTN(element)
{
    var val = element.parent().parent().next("#DeviceType").val();
}
```

**EDIT:**
If you are getting `Undefined` error in the javascript console for the above code, do `Inspect Element` in Chrome, find out the ClientID of `DeviceType` and replace it there.

**EDIT 1:**
See the changed code above. I have changed `this` to `element`. I think that could have been the problem.

**EDIT 2:**
I have tested this and it is working.
Replace your

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="DeviceType" runat="server" Value='<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("DeviceType")) %>' />
```

with

```
<div class="DeviceTypeClass">
    <asp:HiddenField ID="DeviceType" runat="server" Value='<%# string.Format("{0}", Eval("DeviceType")) %>' />
</div>
```

And use the following javascript function:

```
function SelectRBTN(element) {
    var val = $(element).parent().parent().find(".DeviceTypeClass")
        .find(":first-child").val();
}
```

Comment: 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WzKitRegister_dlKit_ctl05_DeviceType' this id getting. but output same for that.

Comment: if i replace deviceType to 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WzKitRegister_dlKit_ctl05_DeviceType' like ` alert($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_WzKitRegister_dlKit_ctl05_DeviceType").val());` than get value but that value same for all node which in datalist. that's wrong.. and if i replace element than giving error on firebug is'element.parent is not function'.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it

Solution 1

1. Add one more parameter in javascript:SelectRBTN(this,selectedDeviceType);
2. In Server get the clientID of "hfSelectedDeviceType" and pass it to the function.
3. Now in the Javascript set the value (using jquery or any library you want.)

Solution 2

1. In the function SelectRBTN, using jquery find the parent td
2. Find the hidden field and set the value.

Comment: please can you give some example for this code. I found parent Id but hidden field value from this not found.

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWcYj/)

**JS**

```
function SelectRBTN(obj)
{
    alert($('#DeviceType').val());
}
```

Comment: in alert getting 'undefined'.

Comment: you need to make sure you id's are static

Answer (score 0):

To get the DeviceType value on the client, you should set ClientIDMode="Static", and then do this to get the value:

```
$("#DeviceType").val();
```

To set:

```
$("#DeviceType").val("new value");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
var val= $("#"+ '<%= hfSelectedDeviceType.ClientID %>').val();
```